# How to add Callback URL to the whitelist in Twitter?

Tags: url, twitter, callback, whitelist

I’m using Twitter API for my own app for almost year now. All was great but after Twitter made some changes I’m receiving the same problem every time:

> Callback URL not approved for this client application. Approved callback URLs can be adjusted in your application settings

The problem is that I can’t whitelist my callback URL. How I can whitelist callback URL? And what I need to do to make my URL whitelisted? What is the whitelisting process in detail? I can’t see any whitelist section or something like that in app settings section.

Comment: Code? Have you written anything?

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to https://apps.twitter.com
2. Click on your application
3. Go to the settings tab
4. Scroll to the "Callback URLs"
5. Type your callback url in the input beneath "Callback URLs"
6. Click "Add a Callback URL"

[Image with whitelist section highligthed in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pIHl.png)

Answer (score 0):

### **October 2021**

1. Go to https://apps.twitter.com
2. Go to the **Dashboard** or **Projects & App** tab
3. Click on the settings icon for your app
4. Enable **3-legged OAuth** under **Authentication Settings**
5. Enter the URL under **Callback URLs**